# XCode iPhone simulator does not look like an iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, instruments

Silly question, but.. I am not been able to see the device appearance when running the iPhone simulator. I don't remember after which XCode update this started but the iPhone simulator **shows only as a simple window without showing the device case like it used to be** (see this [image](http://psnow85.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/xcode4.png)).

That's how my simulator looks like:

[image: simulator]

Is there a way to make it look like an actual iPhone 5?

EDIT: Unfortunately in my hardware->device options I see only iPhone retina (which is currently selected), but there are no more options. So it seems like the default beheaviour to look like a thin window, unless I missed out some other configuration.

Here is what I see overlayed to a user answer.

[image]

Comment: It does this with retina devices.

Comment: If you got a bigger display then the iPhone Simulator (scale 100%) it will work. :P

Answer (score 13):

The Simulator window only shows an iPhone (4/4s) bezel when:

1. The simulated device is a 3.5 inch non-Retina iPhone, *and*
2. The window scale is 100%.

In Xcode 5, you can't do the first one unless you download the iOS 6.1 simulator, because 3.5 inch non-Retina devices are not supported by iOS 7.

(For simulated devices other than 3.5-inch non-Retina, you'll also see a bezel at 100% scale, but this bezel doesn't look exactly like any particular device.)

If you want device images to use in promotional artwork for your app, see Apple's [App Store Marketing Resources](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/index.html) page.

Comment: +1 for the marketing resources link - I'd forgotten about that.

Answer (score 5):

First of all this does with retina devices.

**STEP 1:** Follow this step if you using `Xcode 5` as you need to download the `iOS` simulator.

Go to `XCode`,

- Open the main XCode `Preferences` option then `Downloads`. Click on
  `iOS 6 Simulator` Change to the simulator you want by going to the
  "Hardware" menu. Close the simulator. Run the project.

**STEP 2:**

As you required just change device from Hardware -> device to iPhone as shown in the image.

[image]

And in the next step be sure set the window scale to `100 %`.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the edit, but unfortunately is not about scaling the simulator but is about showing the simulator hardware appearance (the actual aspect of an iPhone which does not show). Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: Actually it is correct to use CMD+1 because http://demosthenes.info/blog/564/Understanding-Pixel-Density-Resolution-and-Retina-Displays Also note that you can then use ^+CMD+SHIFT+4 to "rule the size" of the elements in your screen, yeah an iphone has almost the same pixels as the screen you are probably using now... that is why on 100% looks so big ;).

Comment: @tyoc213 Yeah, you are right. scale can do with `CMD+1` or `+2` or `+3` nice one.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason it looks like an iPhone on my retina Macbook Pro, but not on my iMac.
They're probably looking at the resolution of the Mac, which doesn't really make sense, since you see less at 2880x1800 retina, than 1920x1080 non retina.

Comment: yep, I agree.. it should work. I tried on my MacBook Air and there is the same problem. It used to work on my 2009 iMac. I need to find out a way to enable this :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem I think is not with your XCode, but with your display. Check this : [iPhone skin on Simulator](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/2/25/xcode-fix-show-the-iphone-simulator-skin-on-a-retina-display)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it works like that for anything else - there is no option to show a case for any other simulators.

Comment: iPhone Retina 4-Inch is iPhone 5

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check this Goto IOS Hardware >>Device >>iPhone
then window +1

Comment: then  window +1 press then ??then run it and show simulator screen shot

Comment: the window + 1 is a shortcut to scale to 100% the simulator window, but does not change the aspect of the simulator. In my case (please see screenshot, it look like a plain Mac Os window and not as a device like it should look like).

Comment: yes, but what else should I select? Also if I select the other devices it look like a plain window..

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely correct, im using IOS simulator 7.0, there is no option regarding this. i did every   possible step to make it look like iPhone but hard luck IOS simulator not having this option in Devices.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue also. As indicated earlier, I went to preferences, downloads and then clicked on the ios 6.1 download. After installing it gave me the option of the "iphone". This option actually looks like the iphone. After the install it still includes the retina options as well.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a scaling issue. In the simulator toolbar, go to Window -> Scale, and make sure that 100% is checked. Regarding how to enable iPhone non-retina if not shown, I wrote some steps in [my blog](http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/enabling-iphone-non-retina-in-xcode-5.html) on how to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately it was set to 100% scale already.. thanks anyway :)