# IOS-Simulator in Xcode does not show iPhone -like but regular window

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

It used to work properly, with 100% as well as 50%. Then I did not use the simulator for some time but only the console, having moved the simulator almost out of site. Now I need it but realize that instead of an iPhone surface just a regular window is shown, like in this thread:

[XCode iPhone simulator does not look like an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245853/xcode-iphone-simulator-does-not-look-like-an-iphone)

I read lots of proposal I found on the web to this problem and followed the advices.
So I changed the size to 100%, tried different iPhone devices. And finally I deleted the Xcode application from the application folder and removed all remaining items by putting in the order

sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

into the terminal.
I downloaded Xcode again.

The problem is still there.

The very strange thing about it: It did work properly when I installed Xcode for the first time, about 6 weeks ago.

Comment: Down voter please comment first and @user what have you searched [please review](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19245953/1603380)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it depends on the deployment target whether the simulator shows the iPhone frame or not. I think if you set iOS 7 as the target you won't be able to see the iPhone image around your app screen. (For example, I have never seen an iPhone image in the simulator for a 4'' device.)

Try changing the deployment target and play around with different devices under Hardware / Device in the simulator.

### Edit:

Here is a [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19254643/2062785).
It's one of the replies to the question that you linked.

Answer (score 0):

You better select your simulator and set Hardware -> Device -> iPhone

Note 1: If you want the simulator should looks like iPhone do not select the retina simulator.

Note 2: You must check the target version of you app in xcode it must be below 7.0

Note 3: Keep the scale of simulator always 100%.

Comment: I cannot select a non-Retina iPhone in the checkbox. There is none.

Comment: /Users/danielo/Desktop/Bildschirmfoto 2014-01-03 um 16.51.37.png

Comment: Somebody informed me that Apple does not support anymore the visual iPhone shell anymore in the newest iOS-Simulator as it is not possible anymore to select an iPhone without Retina display as a device.

Comment: I don't understand: "You must check the target version of your app in xcode it must be below 7.0"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the current project you're working on is an iOS and not an OS X project? You can verify this be looking at the project's folder. If the app ist for OS X, there is most likely a .xib file. If it's a iOS project, there should be a storyboard file.

As the OS X apps use windows, like the one you described, this could be a hint.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a storyboard file

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for the problem I had (and other users as well):

At PREFERENCES / DOWNLOADS older versions of the iOS simulator are available. While at the moment the current version is 7.0 (beginning January 2014), versions 6.0 and 6.1 are being offered for download.

After downloading I could chose more devices than with version 7.0. Now also the non-Retina iPhone is available.

As a result, the iPhone surface is being displayed when set to 100% (at WINDOW - SIZE).

Thanks to everyone helping!