# Does iOS Simulator 7.0 have iphone 5 frame?

Tags: ios-simulator

I tried to get frame of iphone 5 in iOS simulator 7 but still its showing rectangular simulator without iphone frame. Want to know that Xcode 5 with iOS simulator 7.0 having the frame of iphone 5 or not?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Longer answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245853/xcode-iphone-simulator-does-not-look-like-an-iphone/19254643#19254643

Comment: This is the [third time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771737/how-can-i-make-ios-simulator-7-0-look-like-iphone-5) you've asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772501/how-to-set-the-frame-for-iphone-5-in-ios-simulator-7-0) in an hour.

Comment: @ Michael bcuz im not getting proper answer.just tell me is it possible to get iphone 5 frame in iOS 7 simulator? please

Comment: if you're not getting the answer you want, you should edit and re-word the original question, not add the same question over and over again.  You ultimately get to choose the best answer (and accept it, which gives reputation points) that works for you.  Wasting peoples' time with multiple versions of the same question is not a very friendly way to get started on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by frame you mean the bezel graphic that looks like an iPhone, then no. The non-retina simulator has a iPhone 4 styled bezel (which never made sense) but retinal simulators don't - presumably because the retina simulator has a hard enough time fitting on most screens without adding a lot of extra padding.

iPhone visuals are (or were) available from apple's marketing resources site, I think you need a developer login to access them, and there are various usage rules.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. now it is confirmed that iOS 7 not having iphone 5 frame. I have been trying to get iphone 5 frame from last 8 days and every time got failed.