# How to get iPhone simulator 7.1 skin same like iPhone in Xcode 5.1.1 or Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5, ios-simulator

If I select normal iPhone simulator in Xcode 5 or Xcode 5.1.1, I am able view simulator same as an iPhone.

But, if I try the same thing with a 4-inch iPhone simulator, retina or non retina, (iOS 6.0, 7.0, 7.1), I'm not able to view simulator like iPhone. It's just showing only the screen, but not the skin or body?

I have tried to select iPhone 4-inch simulator and window scale 100% but it is just showing very big simulator.

If I do same thing for the normal iPhone simulator, it works fine and simulator shows like iPhone, but not for 4-inch simulator. How to get that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode iPhone simulator does not look like an iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245853/xcode-iphone-simulator-does-not-look-like-an-iphone)

Comment: i know these commands which you have mentioned its requirement we need it.please let use know if you got any information which i asked

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would depend on your screen size, because I have the same "problem". However, it shouldn't be an issue.

- If you need the home button functionality, you can just press `Shift-Command-H`
- If you need to lock, it's just `Command-L`

That should be all you need in terms of what the skin can do...otherwise I don't really see the point in needing the skin.

Comment: But why would you need the skin? It doesn't provide any advantage

Comment: i know these commands which you have mentioned its requirement we need it.please let use know if you got any information which i asked

Comment: But i ask again: **what would you need the skin for?** it provides no advantage

Comment: i know there  to advantage but still i need it for know it for my self
how to get it?

Comment: Look. Unless you get a full retina screen, there's no way you're going through get the iphone skin.

Comment: okay i Understand that if i use mac with retina screen then i will see that. thank you.

Comment: Very late, but there are lots of reasons for displaying the skin: sales demos, creating training videos, creating advertising and marketing videos that are _outside_ the App Store, and more. That you can have the functionality of the phone without displaying the skin doesn't meet the need to display the skin. The OP wasn't able to articulate it clearly, but you can be sure there are lots of good reasons to be able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The skin makes sense to have for making app preview videos. Now that we can add preview videos to the app store, we can't use the simulator to make a real looking phone simulation

Answer (score 0):

While the iOS Simulator doesn't let you display the device skin/chrome, there are third-party tools that can. For example, I use an app called [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) that basically makes your Mac look like an Apple TV on the network. You AirPlay the app as it runs on your device (not the simulator) to the Reflector app on your Mac. It, in turn, displays the screen and the skin/chrome around it.

(Looking for the URL, I just noticed that it now lets you display on Windows and allows you to "cast" Android apps as well.)